# How can I turn a json object into 2 sql tables?

Tags: sql, json, sql-server, t-sql

I have a JSON object that looks like this:

```
{
    "headers": { "Employee": [ "Id", "Name", "Salary", "DepartmentId"], 
                 "Department": ["Id", "Name"]
               }, 
    "rows": { "Employee": [
                              [1, "Joe", 70000, 1], 
                              [2, "Jim", 90000, 1], 
                              [3, "Henry", 80000, 2], 
                              [4, "Sam", 60000, 2], 
                              [5, "Max", 90000, 1]
                          ], 
              "Department": [ [1, "IT"], [2, "Sales"] ]
            }
}
```

I am trying to insert the values found under the json object's `$.rows` into the `Employee` and `Department` tables. I put example tables below. I am using SQL Server Express.

I have tried using `JSON_QUERY` and `OPEN_JSON` unsuccessfully

Employee:

```
+----+-------+--------+--------------+
| Id | Name  | Salary | DepartmentId |
+----+-------+--------+--------------+
| 1  | Joe   | 70000  | 1            |
| 2  | Jim   | 90000  | 1            |
| 3  | Henry | 80000  | 2            |
| 4  | Sam   | 60000  | 2            |
| 5  | Max   | 90000  | 1            |
+----+-------+--------+--------------+
```

Department:

```
+----+----------+
| Id | Name     |
+----+----------+
| 1  | IT       |
| 2  | Sales    |
+----+----------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One method is with [`OPENJSON`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openjson-transact-sql), specifying the path to the entities and a `WITH` clause to extract the values of each array entry.

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Employee (
     ID
    ,Name
    ,Salary
    ,DepartmentId
)
SELECT
     ID
    ,Name
    ,Salary
    ,DepartmentId
FROM OPENJSON(@json, '$.rows.Employee')
WITH (
     Id             int         '$[0]'
    ,Name           varchar(50) '$[1]'
    ,Salary         int         '$[2]'
    ,DepartmentId   int         '$[3]'
);

INSERT INTO dbo.Department (
     ID
    ,Name
)
SELECT
    ID
    ,Name
FROM OPENJSON(@json, '$.rows.Department')
WITH (
     Id             int         '$[0]'
    ,Name           varchar(50) '$[1]'
);
```